# How to populate unused flash for an armv7a processor?

Tags: arm7

I have a decision on how to fill unused memory in a flash device.  I've heard of populating with reset instructions as a safe way to handle rogue pointers, etc.  Is there a concept of an assembly reset instruction for armv7a processors?  Is there an industry standard on how I should fill the contents of this flash?  Default erased 0xFF values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think there is an industry standard. However:

### Code

Conveniently, all `0xff` is an undefined instruction for both *arm* and *thumb* encoding (according to `objdump`).  That means if your program counter happens to wind up in empty flash space, your system will take an exception.  Your exception handler can then reset the system to recover.

### Data

Also `0xffffffff` conveniently is an odd number.  This means that when dereferenced as word-sized pointer, it will trigger a bus fault.  This exception you can also handle to reset your system.